# Using AWS Lambda functions in Amazon Neptune

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-neptune

I created an AWS Lambda function using this example code in AWS neptuneDB documentation. I followed documentation properly and set the all necessary lambda environmentale variables as well. But when I tested the function it raises an error. Could you please help me solve this issue. I wonder why the code in the AWS neptunedb documentation does not work.

code:

```
import os, sys, backoff, math
from random import randint
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.driver.protocol import GremlinServerError
from gremlin_python.driver import serializer
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketClosedError
from tornado import httpclient 
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
from botocore.credentials import ReadOnlyCredentials
from types import SimpleNamespace

reconnectable_err_msgs = [ 
  'ReadOnlyViolationException',
  'Server disconnected',
  'Connection refused'
]

retriable_err_msgs = ['ConcurrentModificationException'] + reconnectable_err_msgs

network_errors = [WebSocketClosedError, OSError]

retriable_errors = [GremlinServerError] + network_errors    

def prepare_iamdb_request(database_url):
    
  service = 'neptune-db'
  method = 'GET'

  access_key = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  secret_key = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
  session_token = os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
  
  creds = SimpleNamespace(
    access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key, token=session_token, region=region,
  )

  request = AWSRequest(method=method, url=database_url, data=None)
  SigV4Auth(creds, service, region).add_auth(request)
  
  return httpclient.HTTPRequest(database_url, headers=request.headers.items())
    
def is_retriable_error(e):

  is_retriable = False
  err_msg = str(e)
  
  if isinstance(e, tuple(network_errors)):
    is_retriable = True
  else:
    is_retriable = any(retriable_err_msg in err_msg for retriable_err_msg in retriable_err_msgs)
  
  print('error: [{}] {}'.format(type(e), err_msg))
  print('is_retriable: {}'.format(is_retriable))
  
  return is_retriable

def is_non_retriable_error(e):    
  return not is_retriable_error(e)
    
def reset_connection_if_connection_issue(params):
  
  is_reconnectable = False

  e = sys.exc_info()[1]
  err_msg = str(e)
  
  if isinstance(e, tuple(network_errors)):
    is_reconnectable = True
  else:
    is_reconnectable = any(reconnectable_err_msg in err_msg for reconnectable_err_msg in reconnectable_err_msgs)
    
  print('is_reconnectable: {}'.format(is_reconnectable))
    
  if is_reconnectable:
    global conn
    global g
    conn.close()
    conn = create_remote_connection()
    g = create_graph_traversal_source(conn)
   
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.constant,
  tuple(retriable_errors),
  max_tries=5,
  jitter=None,
  giveup=is_non_retriable_error,
  on_backoff=reset_connection_if_connection_issue,
  interval=1)
def query(**kwargs):
  
  id = kwargs['id']
  
  return (g.V(id)
    .fold()
    .coalesce(
      __.unfold(), 
      __.addV('User').property(T.id, id)
    )
    .id().next())
    
def doQuery(event):
  return query(id=str(randint(0, 10000)))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  return doQuery(event)
  
def create_graph_traversal_source(conn):
  return traversal().withRemote(conn)
  
def create_remote_connection():
  print('Creating remote connection')
  
  return DriverRemoteConnection(
    connection_string(),
    'g',
    pool_size=1,
    message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0())
  
def connection_string():
  
  database_url = 'wss://{}:{}/gremlin'.format(os.environ['neptuneEndpoint'], os.environ['neptunePort'])
  
  if 'USE_IAM' in os.environ and os.environ['USE_IAM'] == 'true':
    return prepare_iamdb_request(database_url)
  else:
    return database_url
  
conn = create_remote_connection()
g = create_graph_traversal_source(conn)
```

error message:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'GraphTraversal' object is not callable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "69e6ecd3-1291-4d21-a8fa-1fc910525fc1",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 111, in lambda_handler\n    return doQuery(event)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 108, in doQuery\n    return query(id=str(randint(0, 10000)))\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/backoff/_sync.py\", line 105, in retry\n    ret = target(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 99, in query\n    return (g.V(id)\n"
  ]
}
```

log output:

```
LOGS    Name: cloudwatch_lambda_agent   State: Subscribed   Types: [Platform]
Creating remote connection
EXTENSION   Name: cloudwatch_lambda_agent   State: Ready    Events: [INVOKE,SHUTDOWN]
START RequestId: 69e6ecd3-1291-4d21-a8fa-1fc910525fc1 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] TypeError: 'GraphTraversal' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 111, in lambda_handler
    return doQuery(event)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 108, in doQuery
    return query(id=str(randint(0, 10000)))
  File "/var/task/backoff/_sync.py", line 105, in retry
    ret = target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 99, in query
    return (g.V(id)END RequestId: 69e6ecd3-1291-4d21-a8fa-1fc910525fc1
REPORT RequestId: 69e6ecd3-1291-4d21-a8fa-1fc910525fc1  Duration: 108.64 ms Billed Duration: 109 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 88 MB  Init Duration: 1025.72 ms
```

Comment: I believe that code is intended to work as-is and just from reading it in a text editor it looks OK. However, the error message implies that a Python object, in this case a GraphTraversal (which would probably be `g` ) is being referenced as if it were a function such as `g()`. As time allows I will try to look at this some more but I would focus your debugging on looking to see if that is happening.

Comment: In tests using the code copied directly from the documentation, it worked fine as is. Is it possible something about the code you have, or your environment, is in some way different?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I added environment variables as mentioned in the documentation. Should I make any changes from the Neptune DB side??

Comment: So long as your code (Lambda) has access to the Neptune VPC everything else should be fine. Just for completeness which version of the Gremlin Python client is your Lambda function configured to use?

Comment: In tests both the code you posted above and the code in the documentation worked unchanged. This one is puzzling. The error implies the GraphTraversal is in some way being used as a function (which would cause the error) but the error does not seem to correlated to the code. Will do some more experiments and report back with any findings.

Comment: One thing we did spot is that the example in the documentation uses the older 3.4.1 Gremlin Python client (which is Tornado based). It would need to be modified to work with the newer clients that are AIOHttp based (to use a library like `requests` for the HTTP operations rather than the Tornado equivalent. However that should not cause the error you are seeing. Also to clarify, in my comment above when I wrote `g()` I should have used something like `g.V('a').out()` as the example as the former is a GraphTraversalSource and the latter a GraphTraversal